# Find eigenvalues of the matrix found in an important paper

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $V = (V_{1},\ldots, V_{T})^{'}$ is a $T \times 1$ vector, and define the demeaned version of $V$ as $\dot{V}=V-\bar{V} \iota_{T}$, where $\bar{V}=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}V_{t}$ and $\iota_{T}$ is just a $T \times 1$ vector of $1$s.

Now define a matrix $M = \frac{\dot{V}\dot{V}^{'}}{T} + b(I_{T} - T^{-1}\iota_{T} \iota^{\prime}_{T})$, where $I_{T}$ is a $T\times T$ identity matrix and $b$ is just a positive constant. Note that $\dot{V}^{'}\iota_{T} = 0$.

Why does it hold that the eigenvalues of $M$ can be given by the following?
\begin{equation*}
\lambda_{i}\text{=}%
\begin{cases}
T^{-1}\dot{V}^{'}\dot{V} + b, \; i=1; \\ 
b, \; 2\leq i \leq T-1; \\
0, \; i=T.
\end{cases}%
\end{equation*}
I do not know how to derive these results.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $M$ is constructed out of $\dot{V}$ and $\iota_T$, it makes sense to see how it acts on them.

We find that $M\iota_T =0$ and $ M \dot{V} = \left(\frac{\dot{V}^\mathrm{T} \dot{V}}{T} +b\right) \dot{V}$. So that’s two of the desired eigenvalues/eigenvectors.

Now consider any third vector, $w$, which is orthogonal to both $\dot{V}$ and $\iota_T$. We find that every vector like this obeys $Mw=bw$. There are $T-2$ independent vectors, which proves the statement.

The reasoning above doesn’t quite work if $V\propto \iota_T$. In this case $\dot{V}=0$ and this isn’t an eigenvector. However, there are now $T-1$ independent vectors $w$ orthogonal to $\iota_T$ with eigenvalue $b$. So although the eigenvectors differ, the set of eigenvalues turns out to be the same.